# Swiftui + Firestore - Cannot access field in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

trying to access a specific field in Firestore, but can't seem to figure it out. In my document, I have a map like this:

[image: data structure]

The below is my code. Hour just returns nil for some reason. I've tried a number of different things including ["notificationTime"]["hour"], but can't seem to figure it out. Any idea? Thanks!

```
self.db.collection("routines").whereField("name", isEqualTo: routineName).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print ("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let hour = document.data()["notificationTime.hour"]
                print(hour)
                return
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you log document.data()?

Answer (score 2):

To read data from a map, use the following approach:

```swift
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("routines").whereField("name", isEqualTo: routineName).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
  if let err = err {
    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
  } 
  else if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
    for document in querySnapshot.documents {
      let results = document.data()
      if let notificationTime = results["notificationTime"] as? [String: Any] {
        let hour = notificationTime["hour"] as? Int ?? 0
        let minute = notificationTime["minute"] as? Int ?? 0
        // ... further handling of your data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That being said, I'd like to suggest looking into `Timestamp`s for storing date-time related data. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp) for more details.